# How to accelerate deletion of data from table which is 0.5 Terabyte in size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-delete, database-performance

I have a large table having 3 columns of datatype INT , Varchar(x) and Image .It contains 1.9 million records and I need to delete specific 1.8 million records .I have tried following code but it itself took 2.5 days.It has 1 Primary key on INT column.

```
SELECT D.Column_A INTO #TEMP
FROM Large_Table D
JOIN Table_C C ON D.Columm_A = C.Column_X
JOIN Table_B B ON C.Column_Y= B.Column_Z
JOIN Table_A A ON A.Column_W= B.Column_Q
WHERE LEFT(A.Column_T,3) = 'abcd'
  SET ROWCOUNT 50000 RECORDS_DELS :
  DELETE A
  FROM Large_Table A
  JOIN #TEMP B ON A.Column_A = B.Column_A IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 GOTO RECORDS_DELS
  SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: Maybe faster to copy the remaining 0.1 million records to a new table, truncate the old one and copy back.

Comment: how about select those 1000 records you want to keep to another temp table and delete all the records? After that, insert those 1000 records to your large table.

Comment: @Thilo  Seems good option. I can try for the same today.

Comment: @Loser Deleting the whole itself taking huge time. May be Truncate could be better option. Will try this new option for sure today.

Comment: @Thilo I hope Truncate will be much faster than Delete since my target is to achieve this process in 5-6 hours instead of 2.5 days

Comment: @Thilo Yes Truncation worked but as per our DBA it takes lot of time for database to release the space somewhat around 5-6 days.